# Disconnected Ubuntu patch server

Tags: apt

I am a RHEL guy, and I just started working in an all Ubuntu environment. I need to get regular Ubuntu patching done - both desktop and server - on a monthy basis.

The problem is, the environment is in a disconnected network. This appears to be the dead end of setting up future patches for the repo, as apt-mirror is unable to keep the repos in sync. I have to sneaker-net the patches in on a USB drive, or burn DVD's.

I inherited a base patch repository, and we were able to upload some cherry picked patches to satisfy the security scans, but we couldn't get the patches to work from the repo server. When we added them to the other deb files in the ubuntu-archive directory, the client was never able to see them. We wound up copying the new patches to the client, and installing locally.

The question is: Is there a way to get a tar ball, or ISO, or some type of large grab of the new patches, and implement them into the old repo without the use of apt-mirror?

Comment: The problem is; when the patches are added to the server, the client does not see them as an upgrade. When we upgraded our systems, the same patch version of the apps are being flagged.

Comment: I can go the the http site and drill down to the updated packages. I can see the version I need on the website. I can even take the URL from the website, and drill down via CLI to get to the package. I know it's there

For instance, I can see Firefox 78. we are being hit for version 73. I attempt an apt-get install firefox, but it tells me it is already to the latest version (73). 

I then copy that 78 package to the client, and it installs flawlessly.

Comment: There are Release complaints, but Mr Google has given me 15 different ways to bypass it, but not fix it.

Comment: perhaps this will help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline/ -- If you get stuck please edit your original question and include the exact errors you're getting - this is essential info for diagnosing the issue.